# Circuitikz short label interferes with arrow

Tags: labels, circuitikz

Why does the short label `l=` interfere with the arrow marker and how do I fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[european,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,2) to [short,l=$i(t)$, i=~] (1,2) to [short] (4,2);
    \draw (0,0) to [short,f=$i(t)$     ] (1,0) to [L, i_=$i(t)$, l_=$L$, v^<=$u(t)$](4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the label element `l` if you want to add currents to your circuit. To add currents `CircuiTikz` provides the current option `i` or the flow option `f`.

If the distance of the current element is still to small you can customize the style of the current element by changing `bipole current style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[european,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
    bipole current style/.style = {
        draw=red, 
        text=black,
        thick,
        fill=orange,
        yshift=0.2cm,
        inner ysep=6pt},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,2) to [short,i>=$I_1(t)$] (1,2) to [short] (5,2);
    \draw (0,0) 
        to [short,f=$I_2(t)$] ++(1,0) 
        to [L, l_=$L$, v^>=$u(t)$] ++(2,0) 
        to [short, i>=$I_2(t)$] ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice!  Can you answer the follow up, or do I move it to a separate question?

Comment: I doubt that `tex.stackexchange.com` is the right place for the question. You may ask at https://electronics.stackexchange.com